# External authorization works on Azure - how to replicate on localhost

Tags: asp.net, azure, authentication, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure website (built using VS2015 Community) which uses "social" login for authentication.

I have successfully deployed a working PoC to azure which happily authenticates the user using the Google+ or Microsoft Account authentication services - i.e. the Azure app service is configured correctly to support social login from these two providers.

The problem is that I don't know how to replicate this for development on localhost; when clicking on one of these links (e.g. the MS one) the browser navigates to `http://localhost:60380/.auth/login/microsoftaccount` and I unsurprisingly get HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found.

**Question**: is there a way I can configure my solution/local environment to authenticate using social authentication whilst running on localhost?  Service providers such as Google seem to have no issue letting you specify localhost addresses.

My website has some very basic authorization checks that I want to perform, and I obviously want to do this on my dev environment first.

For your reference - HTML / Login links:

```
<a href="/.auth/login/microsoftaccount">Microsoft Account</a>
<a href="/.auth/login/Google">Google Account</a>
```

Google API Manager Config - Authorized JavaScript origins

```
https://[my site].azurewebsites.net
http://localhost:60380
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, I assumed that you are using [Authentication/ Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview) of Azure App Service which provides you with an easy way to protect your application without changing any code on your app back-end.

As I known, when your app hosting on Azure then you could take advantage of the "Easy Auth" feature. But while developing locally, I assumed that you need to write your code to support "social" login for authentication. For more details, you could follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on).

Additionally, you could follow this [Architecture of Azure App Service Authentication / Authorization](http://cgillum.tech/2016/02/01/architecture-of-azure-app-service-authentication-authorization/) and this [tutorial](https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/) for a better understanding of Easy Auth.

Comment: your general understanding of my situation is correct.  That said, the first tutorial you mention is excellent but is for a more full-blown OWIN type solution, where-as I'm after a bare-bones approach.

Answer (score 2):

The integrated identity support is a feature of App Service that cannot easily be moved to localhost development. If you need to test locally on your dev machine, you'll need to simulate the identity component yourself.

If you are building a mobile app, there is some support for local debugging which might be helpful: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/wiki/Local-development-and-debugging-the-Mobile-App-.NET-server-backend

Otherwise, I suggest you create a second web app to use for integrated development/testing. It's not as convenient, but Azure App Service does support remote debugging, etc, through Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, I'm coming to the same conclusion.  Currently I'm using a split code approach where small parts of the code run in either "prod" or "localhost" mode, so that I can run as much of the solution as possible on either environment.  It's not particularly elegant but executes ok (potential security weaknesses notwithstanding - fortunately in this case the threat & risk level is quite low).

Answer (score 2):

I've been battling through the same process. Feels to me like this is a gap - I'd love to see the .auth pipeline included as part of the dev environment.

Currently, I use this the method defined here -  https://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/easy-auth-app-service-authentication-using-multiple-providers, and whilst clumsy, it works for me.